# TYPO3 tx_news: The user sees news of categories for which he is not authorized

Tags: typo3, tx-news

There is a question about the same problem as mine, but the problem is still relevant.

I have several categories of news and each user backend is authorized for one or more of them.
Currently, in the backend module "news administartion", users can view news from all categories.

If users modify an unauthorized news item, there is a message stating that it does not have the rights, but is there a solution for the user to see only the news of the authorized categories, as it was possible with tt_news.

My system: Typo3 7.6.18 - tx_news 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you nned just chose fo user or usergroupo sys category on Tab "
Mounts and Workspaces" - > "Category Mounts:" (without root category). Then your backend user will see in backend news list newses just from this category.

Comment: Thank's. In fact, I stored all my news and categories in a single folder. I was able to fix some of my problem by moving the categories into a specific folder. Now, through the filter button of the WEB news administration module, it has only offered BE users the categories that are allowed to them.The problem is that they can always edit all the news (even that of an unauthorized category). Fortunately, they can not save a change to news from an unauthorized category (error message), but is it possible that they will only display (News adm. module) the news of the categories allowed ?

Comment: That i told you, You need use Access Setting for your be_user (http://prntscr.com/gi7wdh and http://prntscr.com/gi7x8n), like i described. For me work fine in TYPO3 6, 7 and event 8. Also tx_news. And this user will see just news from this category - just this way